# ¿Como mostrar en el navegador una matriz con saltos de linea? php

Tags: php, matrices, matriz

estoy haciendo una matriz 5x5, quiero mostrarla con saltos de linea, ya que al ejecutar la function mostrarMatriz() me muestra todos los valores en una sola fila, asi:

[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20],[21,22,23,24,25]]

y yo quiero que haya un salto de linea por cada fila, o sea que me quede asi:

[[1,2,3,4,5]

[6,7,8,9,10]

[11,12,13,14,15]

[16,17,18,19,20]

[21,22,23,24,25]]

Les dejo el codigo por si lo quieren ver:

```
<?php

function mostrarMatriz(){


$matriz=array(array());

 $numeros=1;

  for ($i=0; $i <5 ; $i++){ 
     for ($j=0; $j<5 ; $j++){

    $matriz[$i][$j]=$numeros++;

            }

                }

       return $matriz;

      }




   ?>


   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
     <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

<?php
include_once"matriz.php";

$mostrarMatriz=mostrarMatriz();
echo  json_encode($mostrarMatriz);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solo tienes que añadir un salto de linea (en caso de html, < br >) despues de que se acabe el for interior:

```
  for ($i=0; $i <5 ; $i++){ 
     for ($j=0; $j<5 ; $j++){
        $matriz[$i][$j]=$numeros++;
    }
    echo "<br>";
  }
```

si quisieras hacer el salto de linea desde terminal, deberias añadir un PHP_EOL:

```
echo PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Al poner solo eso no me funciono , pero despues del $matriz[$i][$j]=$numeros++; , agregue printf("%20d",$matriz[$i][$j]); mas el echo con el br que me dijiste , graciaaas :D , saludos!